# spatie/laravel-backup File Backup on Windows not working

Tags: php, laravel, windows

I was backing up the public folder + the db.
DB get's zipped without a problem and also the file zipping doesn't throw an error.
But in the end the zipped archive only contains the db dump.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently laravel backup does not support windows server. That may be the issue. [Here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v8/requirements)